# Express not rendering the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am quite new with Javascript and Express, and I am currently working on a small project to get myself started with the framework and the language.
I am trying to display a comment that an user would have entered by using a form sending the text value by a POST request, which I then save into a file.
To display them, I read the json file and parse it, then transmit the value to the pug template. Here is the code :

Controller.js

```
module.exports.handle_comment = function handle_comment(comment) {
    try {
        let comments = io_utils.read_JSON_file(__dirname+"/comments.json");
        comments.comments.push(comment);

        io_utils.write_JSON_toFile(comments, __dirname+'/comments.json');

        return comments.comments;
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return [];
    }
}
```

Prof.js

```
router.post('/timer', function(req, res, next) {
    const controller = require('../controllers/timer_controller');
    let commentaires = [];
    if(req.body.comment) {
       commentaires = controller.handle_comment(req.body.comment);
    }

    res.render('timer', {
        etudiant: req.body.etudiant,
        comments: commentaires
    });
});
```

Edit : timer.pug

```
extends layout

block content
    center
        if etudiant
            h1 Timer pour #{etudiant}
        else
            h1 Timer
        p Createur : #{prof}
        div#clockdiv
            div
                span.minutes
                p.smalltext Minutes
            div
                span.seconds
                p.smalltext Secondes

        script.
            var timeInMinutes = 2;
            var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
            var deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInMinutes*60*1000);

            initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
        br
        br
        form.pure-form.pure-form-aligned(action="/prof/timer", method="POST")
            textarea.pure-input-1-2(name="comment", placeholder="Commentaires")
            br
            button.pure-button.pure-input-1-2.pure-button-primary(type="Submit") Envoyer

    h2 Commentaires
    if comments
        each comment in comments
            div.commentaire
                span.nom= comment.author
                p.commentaire= comment.text
                br
```

Somehow, when I click on the "send" button, the page doesn't even get displayed. However, when I remove the line calling the controller function, the page gets rendered.

What am I doing wrong ?

Edit :  I am using fs.writeFileSync to write in the json file

Comment: Are there any errors, warnings, etc. in the console?

Comment: Nothing at all, it just doesn't render anything while that line is there! Not even the indication that I just made a POST request gets printed.

Comment: There are a number of places in your Controller.js which could fail depending on your file and module structure, so I don't think there is enough information.

Comment: I printed the final value that is supposed to get returned and it shows the array. Also, when I print the commentaires variable, it shows everything as it should.

Comment: Are you using any middleware (or anything) to define where your files are located? How does `res.render` know what `'timer'` is? What is `timer`? Is that a html/pug file? Can we see what is in there?

Comment: I guess the middleware is the default express's one since I didn't specify one when creating the project, and it is defined on the main js file (app.js, automatically created, which I edited to take in consideration the routes in prof.js). 
Timer is a pug template, I am editing right now to post it's content :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake and I am posting so whoever faces this problems doesn't lose time looking into their code when there is no programming mistake :)

The problem was that I was running my web server using nodemon, which allows to restart it at every file change to avoid the hassle of shutting it down and starting it back again everytime.
I guess that since I was writing on a file, the server just shut down and started again as soon as the file got saved.

Running it normally using 'npm run start' fixed it all :)

Comment: In my experience with nodemon it doesn't by default restart the server on view changes (pug files). However, the server doesn't need to restart to render view updates to the pug files.
I believe you can change what nodemon watches in its config.

Comment: True, I configured nodemon to ignore the files that I modify during runtime after I knew where the problem was coming from.
I'm not sure wether it restarts the server on view changes, nor over the static files's changes, I didn't pay attention whenever I modified one of these files.